# Method that converts String to Enum for any Enum

Tags: java

I want to create a `method` that can convert a `String` to an unspecific `enum`.
Here's what I've got so far:

```
public static Enum<?> toEnum(Class<Enum> targetEnum, String name) {
        return targetEnum.valueOf(targetEnum, name);
}
```

Something like this...

Comment: What does the `name` represent? The enum constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`Enum.valueOf(Class, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)), which accepts a `Class` of some type extending `Enum` and a `String`.

Comment: Didn't know it was that easy ;). Thanks.